# process state in Unix

Tags: unix, process

I need to understand what happens to a process in Unix when it calls the pause() function.

Considering a simple state diagram with three states: ready, run and wait. If my programm only prints its pid and than makes pause, will the program be indefinitely in "wait" state?

If it does `while(1) { pause() }`,  it will be indefinitely in "wait" state too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the manpage:

> pause()  causes  the  calling  process  (or thread) to sleep until a signal is delivered that either terminates the process or causes the invocation of a signal-catching function.

So the program may not be indefinitely in sleep state ("wait", to use your word). It will leave that state if a signal is received. However, if you enclose the `pause()` call in a tight infinite loop as per your example, the program will run again when a signal is received but promptly go back to sleep.

When signals are received during `pause()`, the signal handler (if any) will run, and control will return to the point right after the `pause()` syscall as soon as the handler returns.